# как установить патч ath10k_improve_tx_rate.patch в ubuntu 18.4

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

как установить патч ath10k_improve_tx_rate.patch в ubuntu 18.4
это патч драйера wifi ath10k. Установлена ubuntu 18,4 при запуске aircrack
wi-fi переводиться в режим монитора но не видит ни одной сети, нашел этот патч 
но не нашел как установить.
я новичек гугл не нашел ответов.

Comment: Короткий ответ: забейте болт. Ответ подлиннее: необходимо приложить патч к исходникам соответствующего модуля ядра, скомпилировать этот модуль и подсунуть его вместо штатного. https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module

Comment: я двое суток разбирался почему у меня груб2 не устанавливается в таргет ситема с uefi после установки системы  вот так бросить все (( а може есть возможность выдернуть из ядра кали линукс ? там вроде патченые дрова